# Camel ReST call

Tags: apache-camel

I am calling a ReST service ( ***GET*** ) for which I do not have an API to easily unmarshall a response.

I am wondering what my best option may be for consuming the response.

One option I see is to create a schema based on a sample response from the
web service call and then generate code from that schema to provide me 
the response object I need.

Another option I see is to simply use **XPath** to pull the data I need from the 
Camel response ...I only need a few fields from the response and I am reasonably 
confidant the ReST signature is stable.

Assuimg I go the XPath route, how would I access the response object ? When
I run a test I am able to see the XML response I need sitting in the Exchange
object ( *exchange.getIn().getBody()* ...then in the cachedOutputStream - ***currentStream*** ) ...problem is that I am not sure how to access that *currentStream* object ...any ideas ?

Comment: Do you have a domain object matching the XML response?

Comment: No ...I could though define an object to match the XML response which would indeed solve the problem ...perhaps that is the best way ...that's partly what I am asking... problem is that such a solution seems fairly brittle ...I know that if I can access that currentStream object off the Exchange, I can get at the XML response ...that also ( if even possible ) may not be best.

Comment: Think I have a found a solution to accessing the XML ...as simple as adding .convertBodyTo(String.class) to http call ....question now is whether this ( in conjunction with XPath ) seems the best approach versus create an Object to represent the response.